# Use of marginpar: problems with Underfull \hbox

Tags: line-breaking, warnings, marginpar

I'm using the latex commnad `\marginpar{}`, however for some reason I get the warning:

```
Underfull \hbox <badness 10000> in paragraph ...
```

each time I create a comment on the margin. Is there any way to avoid this?

This is how I use `\marginpar{}`:

```
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2in}
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar\reversemarginpar
 \renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\footnotesize #1]  {\raggedright\footnotesize #1}}
```

How could I modify the above? I read that `\makebox[0pt]{}` might help - but don't understand how?

Comment: make a _complete_ example, I do not get an underfull hbox

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand `\-`; however, it seems that adding `\raggedright` also in the optional argument to `\oldmarginpar` will work as you want:

```
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\reversemarginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{%
  \oldmarginpar[\raggedright\footnotesize #1]%
    {\raggedright\footnotesize #1}}
```

Comment: Depending on the needs, `\RaggedRight` defined in the package `ragged2e` might produce better results.

Comment: @MMM I concur; the main difference is that `\RaggedRight` allows hyphenation. This may be desired or not.